# Apply condition to mysql query

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is the collection I have as an output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [rma_id] => 1
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => CA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [rma_id] => 2
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3
            [rma_id] => 3
            [product_sku] => 26-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [rma_id] => 1
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => CA
        )

)
```

In this, I want to have records with the same SKU but different subsidiaries only.

Desired output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [rma_id] => 1
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => CA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [rma_id] => 2
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )
 )
```

You see the same product_sku but a different subsidiary.

here is the code.
print_r($collection->getData());

Any thoughts on this ?

TABLE IMAGES :

[image]

[image]

Current mysql query :

SELECT `main_table`.*, `secondTable`.* FROM `mst_rma_item` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `mst_rma_rma` AS `secondTable` ON main_table.rma_id = secondTable.rma_id

Comment: you didn't provide how do you selecting data or it comes from input? i mean if you have to work with arrays only or work can be done with sql query

Comment: Hello @OlD.Castor, please consider it comes from an SQL query.
I have shorten it up for easy to understand.
We can consider it as data from input.

Comment: Are you using Laravel or another framework? Are you wanting to INNER JOIN and GROUP BY?  We prefer that you not provide textual data as a screenshot.  Feel free to export the essential schema and sample data into an online db sandbox (db-fiddle.com or other) so that we can instantly play with your realistic data.

Comment: I am using magento 2 framework.